# Change checkbox selected style within a parent label tag

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styles

I'm trying to change the style of my label:before content when the checkbox is selected, unfortunately since im working in drupal i can't change the HTML structure (really, i just cant so please dont provide answers that imply to change the html structure) so i have to find a way to select the label when the checkbox is selected with css3. So far i cant find a level 3 selector that can help me. Here's the html:

```
<div class="form-type-checkbox form-item-submitted-legal-conditions-1 form-item checkbox">
<label for="edit-submitted-legal-conditions-1"> 
<input required="required" type="checkbox" id="edit-submitted-legal-conditions-1" name="submitted[legal_conditions][1]" value="1" class="form-checkbox"> I accept the <a class="popup-legal" href="#">legal terms and conditons</a> </label>
</div>
```

And here's the css:

```
input {opacity:0;}

.form-item-submitted-legal-conditions-1 > label:before  {
    float:left;
    height:22px;
    width:22px;
    content:"";
    border:1px solid #201747;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: .2em .5em 0 0;
}

.form-item-submitted-legal-conditions-1 input[type=checkbox].form-checkbox:checked ~ label:before {
    background-color: #c8102e;
}
```

Here's a codepen:

[codepen code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWEbag)

Comment: Without JavaScript this is impossible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: its a hack instead of using `label` `pseudo` element i am using `a` `pseudo` element which will give the same effect if `a` tag is not there it will not work http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/KVwdbp

Comment: i want to change the style to the label:before tag @vitorino

Comment: (…) based on the state of its descendant: you can't in CSS. Edit: you could if input was the preceding sibling of label, like `input:checked + label:before` but as you stated that you can't modify HTML code, you should rely on JS instead. Good example with accessibility and progressive enhancement/graceful degradation in mind: http://filamentgroup.github.io/checkboxradio/

Comment: thanks for your answer @FelipeAls, i will have to use jquery yeah.

Comment: This is not working for me, nothing happens when i click on the checkbox:

$('label:has(input[type=checkbox]:checked)').addClass('input-force-style');

Any ideas whats going on ?

Comment: this is the HTML structure, i'm trying to select the input:checked, so i guess the label tag is the parent of the input not the previous sibling, am i wrong ?

    <label>
        <input></input>
    </label>

Comment: You are completely right. I misread the code :$